# I don't understand this pun about chickens and math

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

> [math teacher] your homework looks like chicken scratch, but you got them all correct
>   [later at home] I think she's on to us, mathmachicken

I didn't get the above chicken pun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [chicken scratch](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chicken-scratch)
>   Illegible handwriting resembling the marks left by chicken feet on the ground : can't read his chicken scratch on the grocery list

In other words, the teacher is saying that the student's handwriting is difficult to read, but that the answers are all right.

*Mathmachicken* is a combination of *mathematician* and *chicken*. The joke is that the mathematician chicken actually did the work, resulting in literal chicken scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The joke is based on the premise of "chicken scratch" which means the writing is illegible.

> [This is a counting mathmachicken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5q6xkW_hQY&t=1m0s)

There used to be a similar chicken on display in

> [NYC's Chinatown chicken played tic-tac-toe](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/11/nyregion/chinatown-fair-returns-but-without-chicken-playing-tick-tack-toe.html)

This is not to be confused with

> math-mc-chicken

which is the math kids do when they make golden chicken nuggets disappear

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"*Mathmachicken*" sounds a bit like "*mathematician*", which is a person who does math (okay, not really, they do much more than just that, they study all kinds of math and come up with their own).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of light, play-on-words humor to make most people (who understand puns) to chuckle. There is no deeper or nefarious meaning.